# What is the idiomatic way to create styles for a Reason-React component that depend on props?

Tags: css, reactjs, reason, reason-react

To learn [reason](/questions/tagged/reason) and [reason-react](/questions/tagged/reason-react), I'm working on a simple “Things 2 Do” app (see [source code on GitHub](https://github.com/pahund/todo-list-reason-react/tree/material-ui)).

I have a *TodoItem* component that should be rendered with strike-through style when the item has been completed.

I try to solve this by creating a record with various styles, similar to CSS classes, one root style and one for completed items.

```
type style = {
  root: ReactDOMRe.style,
  completed: ReactDOMRe.style
};

let styles = {
  root: ReactDOMRe.Style.make(), /* add root styles here */
  completed: ReactDOMRe.Style.make(~opacity="0.666", ~textDecoration="line-through", ())
};
```

If the prop *completed* is true, I combine the root style with the completed style, otherwise I just use the root, like this:

```
let style = styles.root;
let style = item.completed ? ReactDOMRe.Style.combine(style, styles.completed) : style;
```

This works, but it seems clunky, so I'm wondering: Is there a more elegant solution, e.g. using a variant and a switch statement?

**What is the idiomatic way to create styles for a Reason-React component that depend on props?**

Here is the full code of my component:

```
type item = {
  id: int,
  title: string,
  completed: bool
};

type style = {
  root: ReactDOMRe.style,
  completed: ReactDOMRe.style
};

let str = ReasonReact.stringToElement;

let component = ReasonReact.statelessComponent("TodoItem");

let styles = {
  root: ReactDOMRe.Style.make(), /* add root styles here */
  completed: ReactDOMRe.Style.make(~opacity="0.666", ~textDecoration="line-through", ())
};

let make = (~item: item, ~onToggle, _) => {
  ...component,
  render: (_) => {
    let style = styles.root;
    let style = item.completed ? ReactDOMRe.Style.combine(style, styles.completed) : style;
    <div style>
      <input
        _type="checkbox"
        onChange=((_) => onToggle())
        checked=(Js.Boolean.to_js_boolean(item.completed))
      />
      <label> (str(item.title)) </label>
    </div>
  }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's anything that can be called idiomatic yet. The area is quickly changing, and even I have some ideas of my own on how to improve it, but this is more or less how I do it now using [bs-css](https://redex.github.io/packages/bs-css):

```rust
module Styles = {
  open Css;

  let root = completed => style([
    color(white),
    opacity(completed ? 0.666 : 1.),
    textDecoration(completed ? LineThrough : None)
  ]);
}

...

  render: _self =>
    <div className=Styles.root(item.completed)>
      ...
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For now, the way I'm styling my component is OK. There is not really an idiomatic way for styling React components in Reason *yet*.

The Reason documentation [has this to say](https://reasonml.github.io/reason-react/docs/en/style.html):

> Since CSS-in-JS is all the rage right now, we'll recommend our official pick soon. In the meantime, for inline styles, there's the ReactDOMRe.Style.make API